# KeystoneJS setup placing files in wrong directory

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

So I run `yo keystone` after install keystone then run through all the setup instructions.

However, it always places it into my `~/` directory even when I add in the option to create a new directory. Thus, all the files conflict with other files in my `~/` directory.

How can I cd into a directory and install it without it placing them all into `~/`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to cd into your directory:

```
mkdir myproject
cd myproject
yo keystone
```